# WSO2 Api Manager + Authentication + Websocket

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

In our architecture there are clients (web or mobile) that connects to the frontend webapp protected with SSO from an authentication filter using WSO2 Identity Server to enforce user login.

I developed a proxy servlet to wrap all invocations to the backend services, this servlet is deployed in the fronted webapp. Everithing works until this point.

The architecture is the following:
User <--> Firewall <--> Apache Proxy <--> Frontend WAR <--> Backend WAR

The problem is that these clients need to connect to a Websocket endpoint deployed on the backend WAR.

Looking around I found that WSO2 Api Manager starting from version 2.1 has the Websocket support.

I tried to follow the provided tutorial: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Create+a+WebSocket+API

But in the example is not mentioned how to connect to the API exposed endpoint using a pure javascript.

Do you have any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Regards

Comment: "using a pure javascript" - you mean how to connect a websocket from the user's client?

Comment: Exactly, from a user web page, running on his browser using the HTML5 WebSocket object

Comment: It's not purpose of the WSO2 APIM. API Manager just pass the request to the backend and response back to the client. In the tutorials it is assumed you know how to implement your websocket client. So you will have to search (google/yahoo/whatever) how to use some JS framework to create a websocket connection. Example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications

Comment: Is exactly what I'm asking for: a best practice to connect to a WebSocket enpoint wrapped by the WSO2 APIM using javascript. The big problem probably is how to set the authentication token.

Comment: I'd assume just send it as an Authorization Bearer header. Ain't that working?

Comment: I'm looking for a working example to put the auth header in the handshake request but with no success...

Comment: @FrancescoFornari were you able to solve the issue? The support for custom headers was just added to the API Manager. Now you can just send any header that you need to the websocket backend.